# Insert a looping list into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a list generated inside a loop operation. In each loop, if I print the list then I get like this:

```
[('E', 5), ('B', 3), ('C', 2)]


[('B', 5), ('D', 3), ('C', 2), ('A', 1), ('E', 7)]
```

I have an empty dataframe with columns as A, B, C, D, E.

How can I insert this generating list into the dataframe as row matching the column name. The list generated in each loop may not have all column's value. That need to replaced with 0.

Code:

```
for document in myCorpus:
transform = tfidfCategory.transform([document])
for value in document.split():
    score[value] = transform[0, tfidfCategory.vocabulary_[value]]
scoreValue = sorted(score.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print ("\t", scoreValue)
print()
```

Output from above code:

```
[('E', 5), ('B', 3), ('C', 2)]
[('B', 5), ('D', 3), ('C', 2), ('A', 1), ('E', 7)]
```

Desired output dataframe:

```
A  B  C  D  E       
0  3  2  0  5        
1  5  2  3  7
```

Please help!

Regards
Sudeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a_list=[('E', 5), ('B', 3), ('C', 2)]

new_row = pd.Series()

map = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D":0, "E":0}

for a in a_list:
    map[a[0]] =a[1]
new_row = pd.Series(map)
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

So we initialize a map to 0 and then populate the desired value in the map. using that create a new row and append in df.
PS:- You need to create a new map for every list.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for your input. I managed to save the data in dataframe following your code.

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try `concat` on list comprehension:

```
scoreValue = [[('E', 5), ('B', 3), ('C', 2)],
              [('B', 5), ('D', 3), ('C', 2), ('A', 1), ('E', 7)]]

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(s).set_index(0).T for s in scoreValue], sort=True)
```

Output:

```
     A  B  C    D  E
1  NaN  3  2  NaN  5
1  1.0  5  2  3.0  7
```

Comment: If I use concat in my for loop, then I am getting the dataframe with only last row and all as columns.

Comment: What if you use `concat` after the for loop, when you already have `scoreValue`?

Comment: So, the scoreValue is holding only last document of myCorpus.

Comment: Thanks Quang Hoang for your quick response and help.